# Change CSS of styled-components with react in Class components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I must change the width of a sidebar using [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) library in React project.

Here is the code in the Class Component :

```
let SidebarStyled = styled.div`
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #0c1635;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  .showFlexInMobile {
    display: none !important;
  }
  p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  @media (max-width: 1024px) {
    width: 70px;
    .hideInMobile {
      display: none !important;
    }
    .showFlexInMobile {
      display: flex !important;
    }
    > .link-logo {
      margin-top: 8px;
      > img {
        width: 50px;
      }
    }
  }
`

const hideSidebar = () => {
  // my code
}


class Sidebar extends Component<ISidebar> {
  render() {
    return (
      <SidebarStyled>
        <SidebarHeaderStyled style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
          <button onClick={hideSidebar} className="buttonSideBar">
            -
          </button>
   [...]
`;
```

On click on the button at the end, I would like a `hideSidebar` function to actually change the width from 200px to 70px.
I usually use hooks to do this, but my client has only Class components.

Anyone can help me on this ?
Thank you very much

Comment: Hi, I added the answer with the class-based component. I think it is very important to refer to this link to understand the class-based component state and event handling in reactjs. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-class-based-components/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add props to your styled tags

https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props
in your case it would look something like

```js
const Somestyled= styled.input`
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  width: ${props => props.somethinghere};
  background: papayawhip;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;
```

and use it looks

```
<Somestyled somethinghere={yourVariableHere} />
```

Comment: this returns the error : ```Property 'sidebarWidth' does not exist on type 'ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | "style" | "title" | ... 252 more ... | "is"> & { ...; }, any>'.``` :/

Answer (score 0):

Hey so the code had a few errors so I corrected the syntax and created [this quick little codepen](https://codepen.io/mahn00b/pen/vYWaYBp?editors=1011) I'm not gonna explain everything I fixed but I will say watch your syntax. You can achieve this quite simply in the JSX and not have to use CSS at all!

You should convert your component over to a functional one since it's the convention these days. But regardless, you need to move the logic of hiding the component in the component itself. In the example I use [React.useState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to toggle a boolean and hide the component. You can also use the [classic class component state management](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) to do this. I also put and example for showing it too. ;) Good luck

```js
const Sidebar = () => {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = React.useState(true);
  
  const hideSidebar = () => {
    setIsShown(false)
  }

  const showSidebar = () => {
    setIsShown(true)
  }
  return (
    <div>
    {
      isShown &&
      (<SidebarStyled>
      <button onClick={hideSidebar} className="buttonSideBar">
        -
      </button>
    </SidebarStyled>)}
      {!isShown && <button onClick={showSidebar} style={{ width: 50, height: 50, marginLeft: 300}}>
        show
      </button>}
    </div>
  );          
}
```

And in a class component:

```js
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   
   this.state = { isShown: false };
 }
  
 hideSidebar() {
    this.setState({ isShown: false});
 }

  showSidebar() {
    this.setState({ isShown: true});
  }
  
  render() {
    const {
      isShown
    } = this.state;
    
    return (
    <div>
    {
      isShown &&
      (<SidebarStyled>
      <button onClick={() => this.hideSidebar()} className="buttonSideBar">
        -
      </button>
    </SidebarStyled>)}
      {!isShown && <button onClick={() => this.showSidebar()} style={{ width: 50, height: 50, marginLeft: 300}}>
        show
      </button>}
    </div>
  ); 
  }
           
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank your for your answer. The problem is my client want only Class Component... with a functional component it would be easy. But I have to deal with Class Components only... :/

Comment: I switched the example up : )

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this

```
//your styled component

class Sidebar extends Component<ISidebar> {
  constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.state = { sidebarShow: true };
    this.hideSidebar = this.hideSidebar .bind(this);
  }

  hideSidebar = () => {
    // your code
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      sidebarShow: false
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <SidebarStyled style={{left: `${this.state.sidebarShow ? '0px' : '-250px'}` }}>
        <SidebarHeaderStyled style={{ position: 'relative'}}>
          <button onClick={this.hideSidebar} className="buttonSideBar">
            -
          </button>
   [...]
`;
```

If you want to handle all styles in the styled component you can add a new attribute in a component

```
<SidebarStyled isShow={this.state.sidebarShow} >
....
</SidebarStyled>
```

And on component

```
let SidebarStyled = styled.div`
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  left: ${props=>props.isShow ? '0px': '-250px'};

...

`
```

It will work for you.